# calling coordinates from Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, mapkit, cllocationmanager

i've been trying to call the latitude and longitude of places that i have stored into the database. I've set the storage type as double.

At the the first view controller, i tried to push the coordinates, and in the log it works fine.

```
-(IBAction) mapsend:(id)sender
{
    DiscoverAllMapViewController *fvController = [[DiscoverAllMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiscoverAllMapViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvController animated:YES];
    double dx = [wher.latx doubleValue];
    double dy = [wher.longy doubleValue];

    fvController.latx =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dx]; 
    fvController.longy =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dy]; 
    NSLog(@"checking latx :%@",fvController.latx);
    [fvController release];
}
```

now at DisplayAllMapViewController, the log seems to always be null. I've tried setting the parsing instance to NSString, NSNumber, double, but it still doesnt send any value.

```
-(void)loadOurAnnotations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {0.2, 0.2};
    double xx = [latx doubleValue];
    double yy = [longy doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"check latx :%f",xx);
    workingCoordinate.latitude = xx;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = yy;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {workingCoordinate, span};
    DiscoverAllMapAnnotation *appleStore1 = [[DiscoverAllMapAnnotation alloc] init];
    [appleStore1 setCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [appleStore1 setTitle:@"Kota Kinabalu"];
    [appleStore1 setSubtitle:@"BOMB!!!!!"];
    [appleStore1 setAnnotationType:DiscoverAllMapAnnotationType1];

    mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
    [mapView addAnnotation:appleStore1];
    [mapView setRegion:region];
    [appleStore1 release];


}
```

please have a look.. thank you

Comment: When is loadOurAnnotations called?  In viewDidLoad of DisplayAllMapViewController?

Comment: @Anna Karenina yes, at viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` of `DiscoverAllMapViewController` happens as soon as you do `pushViewController` which is before you've set the `latx` and `longy` properties.

Move the `pushViewController` call to *after* the properties are set (just before the `fvController release`).